# Set up a table or construct a table or some other expression?

Tags: verbs

Hello, everyone. I want to add a routing table in a router such the router could record essential information in the table and query the table if necessary. What is the correct verb that should be used? Should I say "the router sets up a routing table" or "the router constructs a routing table" or some other expression? Note that since a table cannot be added into the router casually, "the router add a routing table in itself" or so is not appropriate.  Thanks sincerely.
    regards.

Comment: The router will, to start, "set up" or "initialize" the table.  "Construct" is also a reasonable term to use.  Then, as changes come in, it will "update" the table.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the router loads the routing configuration from somewhere (static file, dynamically from network) and updates its routing table with routing configuration entries. So I would say **the router updates the routing table**, but it still sounds not very technical. In case of static configuration a network administrator would enter the configuration directly into some config file, and all the router will do is just read that file, so there is not any set up or construction work, you can just say **router loads the configuration**.

Comment: Thank you. But this is a design I propose myself. In this design, besides the original routing table you mentioned just now, the router will maintain another routing table from a different source if necessary. So I wonder how this operation should be described? regard.

Comment: `the router will maintain another routing table` is perfectly fine